# Asymptotic property concerning the last renewal time of a positive-drift random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk, time-series

Consider a random process $\{X_k\}^\infty_{k=1}$ of independent and identically distributed random variables, with mean value $\mathbb{E}[X_k] = \mu $ and $0<\mu <\infty$. Consider a random process $W_n$ given by the recursion$W_n = \max\{W_{n-1}+X_n,0\}$, with $W_0 =0$. We define $\lambda_n$ as the last time $W_n$ becomes equal to zero (we call this event a 'renewal'), i.e.

\begin{equation}
\lambda_n = \sup\{ \ell \leq n : W_\ell =0\}.
\end{equation}

I am trying to verify whether  $n - \lambda_n \rightarrow \infty$ in some sense (e.g. almost surely, or in probability) as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Intuitively, I think that should hold because of the positive mean value assumption. I would really appreciate if someone could provide any hints or references for this kind problem. Thanks!

Comment: The quantity $n-\lambda_n$ is the backwards recurrence time, or "age" of the renewal process $\{\lambda_n\}$ at time $n$. The key renewal theorem can be used to derive the limiting distribution of age by showing it satisfies a renewal equation. However, this depends on $\mathbb E[W_n]$, which cannot be determined without more information about the distribution of $X_1$.

Comment: Some high level argument: if $n-\lambda_n$ does not diverge to $\infty$, wouldn't that mean that $W_n$ would not be able to drift to $\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, if we assume that the drift $\mu$ is finite?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a contradiction since a random walk with positive drift diverges to $\infty$ with probability 1?

Comment: Yeah, because of the divergence of random walk, it seems clear that $W_n \to +\infty$ and therefore $\sup_n \lambda_n < \infty$ almost surely, which certainly implies your claim.

Comment: You can see this by coupling: let $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$.  Clearly $S_n \to +\infty$ a.s., and by induction you can see that $W_n \ge S_n$ surely for every $n$.